# I am geeting error : ReferenceError: navigation is not defined in react native navigation. I am just learning react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am trying to learn react native but getting following error

**ReferenceError: navigation is not defined**

I am a beginner can you please guide me to solve this error.

I have also tried to change to functional component but getting same error.

I am using expo for learning purpose

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button,ImageBackground } from "react-native";

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello HomeScreen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello profile</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
class App extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profle" component={Profile} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems : 'center'
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a class based component so use this.props.navigation

```
 <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
```

Comment: Getting Error:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')

Comment: @Android can you share your code ?

Comment: renderItem={({ item }) => 
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.props.navigation.navigate('FoodItems')// New component class
                                       }
                        }
                    >
                    <Row {...item} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    }

Comment: @Android is this a screen component ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356842/navigate-to-another-component-on-clicking-flatlist-in-react