# Navigate to another component on clicking FlatList in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

I am using `FlatList` to display `Image` and `Text` side by side in a **Component** screen. I want to click on any row and open a new Component class[FoodItems] and passing just a simple string.

It says, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')".
I have installed all required packages.

`npm install react-navigation`

`npm install @react-navigation/native`

I don't know what `this.props` here is? I am not sending props from previous screen. I just copy paste it from some post.

Restaurants.js:

```
import { View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import withRouter from './withRouter';

class Restaurants extends Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.state.restaurantsSet) {
      this.setState({ restaurantsSet: true });
      this.settingRestaurants(this.props.location.state.station);
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <div className='header'></div>
        <FlatList
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.FlatListHeader} 
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={this.state.restaurants}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
            <TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => 
                this.props.navigation.navigate(
                  'FoodItems',
                  { message: 'my_message' }
                )
              }
            >
              <Row {...item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Restaurants);
```

withRouter.js:

```
import { useLocation, useParams, useNavigation } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  
  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...{props, params}}
      {...{ location, params,}}
      {...{navigation, params}}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter;
```

Comment: Which routing/navigation library are you trying to use here? `react-router` and `react-navigation` are two different and unrelated libraries.

Comment: @DrewReese : Removed extra imports. As we discussed earlier, on clicking <Link> I moved to Restaurants component, where I am displaying FlatList. So, to pass some param through <Link>, I implemented custom withRouter, as you suggested. Also, I posted code in this question. Now, I want to click on FlatList and move to another Component screen called FoodItems.

Comment: @DrewReese: So , I reached @ Restaurants screen using react-router. I would like to move to another screen using router only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `withRouter` HOC is implemented incorrectly. The [`useNavigation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation) hook is a RRDv6.4 Data router only hook. Emphasis mine.

> This hook tells you everything you need to know about a page
> navigation to build pending navigation indicators and optimistic UI on
> data mutations. Things like:
>
> - Global loading indicators
> - Disabling forms while a mutation is happening
> - Adding busy indicators to submit buttons
> - Optimistically showing a new record while it's being created on the server
> - Optimistically showing the new state of a record while it's being updated
>
> Important
>
> ***This feature only works if using a data router***, see [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)
>
> ```
> import { useNavigation } from "react-router-dom";
>
> function SomeComponent() {
>   const navigation = useNavigation();
>   navigation.state;
>   navigation.location;
>   navigation.formData;
>   navigation.formAction;
>   navigation.formMethod;
> }
> ```

The `useNavigation` hook isn't used to issue any imperative navigation actions. For this you should import and use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook as this is the hook that returns the `navigate` function.

```
import { useLocation, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      {...{ location, params, navigate }}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter;
```

The in the React Class component access `this.props.navigate`. Don't forget that data you want to pass in route state is passed in the `option` object's `state` property.

```
import { View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import withRouter from './withRouter';

class Restaurants extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.restaurantsSet) {
      this.setState({ restaurantsSet: true });
      this.settingRestaurants(this.props.location.state?.station);
    }
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <div className='header'></div>
        <FlatList
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.FlatListHeader} 
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={this.state.restaurants}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
            <TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => 
                this.props.navigate(
                  'FoodItems',
                  { state: { message: 'my_message' }}
                );
              }
            >
              <Row {...item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Restaurants);
```

Comment: Error is gone now.  But on clicking FlatList item, it says "No routes matched location "/restaurants/FoodItems" .  Do I need to add route in App.js ?

Comment: @Android Yes, you'll need to render a route with a path that can be matched.

Comment: @Android Certainly, glad to help. Cheers.